# PHPStorm not able to run .php file (Working as .html file)

Tags: php, html, phpstorm

i tried to copy my Login.html to Login.php and run it, using phpstorm 9.

The configuration is fine - since any other scripts etc. are working.
The html file is also running well. Just by converting the file to .php it stops working. The Output suddenly stops without Errors (see screenshot below as example).

When removing all contents of the head, the Output is working. I just can't find any reason / solution for this...

UPDATE: When moving the complete Project in the htdocs Folder of xampp it is working. The php files in my root Folder of the projekt are working when running from phpstorm direcly.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a `.htaccess` issue

Comment: so what can i try? i do not have a single .htaccess file in my project

Comment: That file is on the server, I don't know much about it nut I am pretty sure this is the issue, I was hoping someone else who knows what they are doing would help ya out.